# JS/HTML - Loading <object> without <html>

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I'm creating some kind of gallery and am recently stuck with this:

```js
          function loadGallery() {
               document.getElementById("fullgallerypreview").innerHTML='<object type="text" data="showall.php" ></object>';
          }
```

```html
  <span class="showall" onclick="loadGallery()">
    All
  </span>
  
<div id="fullgallerypreview"> </div>
```

The script is meant to **load showall.php into the #fullgallerypreview** container, and it does - but the result is not quite i wanted.

Here's the code **loaded originally** from index.php:

[image: Good display]

And here's how it looks like when it gets this same code **loaded as object**:

[image: Bad display]

Seems like it wouldn't use css at all, also from Dev Mode in chrome i can say it puts the object with additional html/head/body tags, so maybe this is the cause of the issue?

[image: Object html]

I've already been thinking a while on a workaround, got no clue, maybe you could help me solve it? :)

Also, on Archer's demand, i enclose the showall.php code (removed php part since it contains some personal data and works just fine):

```
<div class="all">                           
    <table class="fullgallerytable">
        <tr>
            <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT id, rozmiar, technika, kategoria, image_time, title FROM {$table} ORDER BY ID ASC");
            if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
                echo '<td><li>Nie wgrano żadnych plików.</td>';
            else
            {
                echo '<td>';
                while(list($id, $rozmiar, $technika, $kategoria, $image_time, $title) = mysql_fetch_row($result))
                {
                    echo "<div class='fullgalleryimage'>";
                    echo "<a href='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id' data-lightbox='fullgaleria' data-title='{$title}, {$technika} | {$rozmiar}'><img width='150' class='wmimage' height='150' src='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."?show=$id'></a>";
                }

                echo '</td>';
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

There are no html/head/body markups in showall.php **AT ALL**, so i believe it should print out pure code without those markups.

Comment: Can you also post showall.php in the question?  If that's returning full html then that's why.

Comment: Edited Q Archer, hope it would lead u somehow!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've tagged the question with jQuery I'll give you a very simple answer to this.  Use the `jQuery.load()` function...

```
$("#fullgallerypreview").load("showall.php");
```

That will perform an AJAX call to load the contents of `showall.php` and then populate the selected div with whatever is returned.

Comment: damn, i swear jquery wouldn't work for me earlier either, but now that you posted it automagically did. problem solved, thanks!

Comment: No problem - glad to help :)